# Xcode 8.1 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, x86-64

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_BROADCAST_MODE_IBEACON", referenced from:
-[MainViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in MainViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TZBeaconSDK", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I take that error when I want to use simulator. There is no problem when I build it on iPhone. There is only problem when I use simulator. I have tried to change Architectures from Build settings, error text changes as i386 but problem is same.

I use that sdk; [TZBeacon](http://development.tzonedigital.cn/Beacon/IOS/SDK_v1.0_20160630.zip)

Is there any problem with sdk? Could you help me to solve that problem?

Comment: Potentially, `libTZBeaconSDK.a` is not Simulator "compatible" (not built for), check the doc.

Answer (score 10):

Your library does not support simulator. Run this command line to see which architecture that it supports:

```
lipo -info libTZBeaconSDK.a
```

the result is: **Architectures in the fat file: libTZBeaconSDK.a are: armv7 arm64**

So, you have to test in a device, not in simulator!

Answer (score 5):

Typically you get that error in the simulator if the architecture of the framework is built for the device. You need to use a version of the framework that is built for the simulator to run it on the simulator. This is something that should be provided by the framework vendor.

If they don't provide one then look into only including that framework when building to the device and not to the simulator. There is another SO answer here to point you in the right direction: [How to only include a framework when building for device, not iOS Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481077/how-to-only-include-a-framework-when-building-for-device-not-ios-simulator)

Answer (score -6):

Simple trick here: **Go** -> **Go To Folder** "**/Library/Developer/Xcode**"
delete **Derived data** next clean your project then **Run** .

Comment: Did not helped. @PrasannaKumar

Comment: Did not helped.