# iOS unable to build dependency on simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

In my app, I am using a dependency which is not buildable on simulator (works fine on devices). When I try to build it for simulator, I get an error:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

If I don't want to perform any operation related to that dependency, is there any way to disable that dependency (without removing) when deploying my app on simulator?

Comment: Try doing `Reset content and settings` and run again.

Comment: Related Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745020/xcode-8-1-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-error, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346637/xcode-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-ios-lib, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559904/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-on-xcode-6-1